# Custom Menu in Excel toolbar using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am tryting to create a custom menu in Excel toolbar, using below code but I am not able to see any entry. Please let me know what could be the problem.

```
Option Explicit

Private Const MY_TAG = "MYXla"
Private Const MY_TOOLS_MENU_ID As Long = 30009&



Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim ToolsMenu As Office.CommandBarControl
    Dim ToolsMenuItem As Office.CommandBarControl
    Dim ToolsMenuControl As Office.CommandBarControl

     Set ToolsMenu = Application.CommandBars.FindControl(ID:=MY_TOOLS_MENU_ID)
        If ToolsMenu Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Unable to access Tools menu.", vbOKOnly
            Exit Sub
        End If

        Set ToolsMenuItem = ToolsMenu.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlPopup, temporary:=True)
        If ToolsMenuItem Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Unable to add item to the Tools menu.", vbOKOnly
            Exit Sub
        End If

        With ToolsMenuItem
            .Caption = "&MY Spreadsheet Solver"
            .BeginGroup = True
            .Tag = MY_TAG
        End With

        Set ToolsMenuControl = ToolsMenuItem.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton, temporary:=True)
        If ToolsMenuControl Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Unable to add item to Tools menu item.", vbOKOnly
            Exit Sub
        End If
End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: You'll need to set the visible property for `ToolsMenu` to True (ie. ToolsMenu.Visible = true).  Also, it looks like you'll need to set the properties for `ToolsMenuControl` (ie. caption, faceid, etc).

Comment: @Domenic, I tried that but no luck

Comment: AFAIK, the Tools menu has ID 30007, not 30009. Moreover, you can no longer modify the Tools menu in current versions of Excel (as of Excel 2007), you should instead be adding Ribbon customization code to your file as Ron de Bruin shows here: http://rondebruin.nl/win/section2.htm

Comment: @Domenic, thanks, it is visible under Add-in, however how to make it visible outside just like we have Home. View, Review etc.

Comment: In that case, you'll need to use XML code, as @jkpieterse has mentioned in his post. Have a look at the link he posted.